# Problem when using !Sub in TemplateURL creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Trying to deploy a nested Cloudformation stack. Works fine if I hardcode the `TemplateURL` as follows -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  MyStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/my-template.yml
```

but as soon as I start to do any string substitution within `TemplateURL` eg

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  MyStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://s3.#{AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/my-template.yml"
```

then on deployment I get -

```
AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | CREATE_FAILED | TemplateURL must be an Amazon S3 URL.
```

I have tried different flavours of `!Sub` and `Fn::Sub`, and with using custom defined variables rather than `AWS::Region`, but always the same result :-/

What am I doing wrong here ?? TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `${AWS::Region}` instead of `#{AWS::Region}` (dollar sign instead of hashtag)

> A string with variables that AWS CloudFormation substitutes with their associated values at runtime. Write variables as ${MyVarName} [...]

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html

Comment: Why and how would that help? Please add an explanation to your (practically) code-only answer. It helps fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free coding service instead of a Q/A community.

Comment: Eh ? That answer was perfect. Nothing else required.